# Как перенаправить все исходящие интернет-запросы устройств на сокет на одном из устройств в локальной сети

Tags: сеть, dns, роутер, dhcp, порты

Доброго времени суток. Имеется ноутбук, роутер Asus RT-N53, и несколько устройств, подключённых к нему по Wi-Fi. Можно ли **все** исходящие интернет-запросы устройств (на любой веб-сервер, IP-адрес в интернете, и т.п. любого TCP-, UDP-порта и т.д.) перенаправить на сокет, запущенный на ноутбуке на порту *x?* То есть, если я открою веб-страницы в браузере по адресу, к примеру, `www.google.com`, `111.222.333.454:666`, `test.abvgd.privet` или `localhost:5555` должна отобразиться веб-страница, которую предоставит мне сокет, запущенный на ноутбуке. Так же, при попытке установить соединение с сокетом по протоколу UDP, чтобы также в ответ получалась моя веб-страница с моего сокета (могу запустить сокет на обоих протоколах TCP и UDP). Как такое реализовать?

DNS-сервер не в помощь, он только домены умеет "перенаправлять", т.е. если я зайду в браузере на веб-страницу `www.yandex.ru`, то сервер сможет перенаправить меня на сокет на ноутбуке в локальной сети, а если я наберу `77.88.55.55` (IP-адрес домена Яндекса), то DNS-сервер об этом запросе не узнает, и пользователь сможет посетить сайт Яндекса.

Comment: Даже если роутер сможет это сделать, то как вы узнаете что это за запросы. для вас это будет просто набор непонятных данных, так как информации о протоколе по которому шел пакет и на какой адрес и порт он был направлен не сохранится (она же будет заменена на один единственный ваш адрес/порт), а следовательно вы не сможете сформировать такой ответ который ожидает получить клиент (он то ожидает получить ответ с того адреса куда посылал пакет, а вы то их не знаете). Это делается по другому, для этого существуют проксирующие протоколы, например socks.

Comment: Если вопрос стоит только в том, что это нужно сделать, тогда вам надо сделать на роутере (если он поддерживает) правило которое производит безусловный редирект для всех пакетов (кроме целевого ноутбука, иначе свои собственные пакеты тоже получите) в цепочке FORWARD на адрес вашего ноутбука. Но смысла в этом действительно немного, какую задачу вы хотите решить?

Comment: А да, если вы вдруг под словом "сокет" имели ввиду все таки socks (который к термину "сокет" не имеет ни малейшего отношения), то вам нужно копать в сторону прозрачного socks, что в прниципе на linux возможно, но в стандартные прошивки роутеров явно не входит

Comment: только если вы измените на роутере таблицу маршрутизации и _весь_ проходящий трафик таким образом направите на себя, т.е. по факту ваша машина станет следующим в цепочке маршрутизатором. Но разумеется ваша машина при этом должна быть в одном физическом сегменте с тем роутером

Comment: Ну или как вариант, измените прошивку роутера, установив туда какой нибудь сниффер вроде tcpdump и будете консолью к нему подключаться и снимать данные с этого снифера

Comment: @Mike, большое спасибо за информацию. А теоретически роутер может сам отвечать на запросы устройств без посредника (без ноутбука с сокетом)?

Comment: В принципе может. если мощьности процессора на обработку хватит. практически все современные роутеры по факту слабенькие компы и прошивка у них специальная сильно порезанная версия linux.

Comment: @Mike, а как таблицу маршрутизации изменить и весь проходящий трафик таким образом направить на себя?

Comment: Достаточно будет использовать существующий дистрибутив, доустановив доп. пакеты как в примере (https://linuxaria.com/article/redirect-all-tcp-traffic-through-transparent-socks5-proxy-in-linux)

Comment: [Посмотрите эту инструкцию](https://www.alexeykopytko.com/2016/tor-transparent-proxy/), может натолкнёт на какие-то идеи. Ещё можно посмотреть на [redsocks](http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/) и [shuttle](http://sshuttle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/how-it-works.html). У них у всех есть исходники.

Comment: Веб-страницу вы по UDP никак не посмотрите.

Answer (score 1):

Та точка, через которую проходят все запросы, обычно, ваш роутер. Значит перехватывать все запросы можно на нём. Если у вас роутер на Linux, что скорее всего, то переадресовать пакеты на порт *на самом роутере* можно так:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j REDIRECT --to-port 9040
```

На другой компьютер в сети тоже можно все переадресовать:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2
```

Затем нужно на том компьютере поймать эти пакеты и переадресовать их на нужный порт.

Может быть проще будет настроить этот компьютер как мост. [Пример такой настройки](https://www.alexeykopytko.com/2016/tor-transparent-proxy/) в целях обхода разных глупых и бесполезных запретов через Tor.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А как `на том компьютере поймать эти пакеты и переадресовать их на нужный порт`?

Comment: Например, пометив пакеты как-то при переадресации. Этот вопрос заслуживает отдельного обсуждения, лучше задать его отдельно.